# What is the meaning of wasps nest symbolism from Neuromancer?

Tags: cyberpunk, neuromancer, william-gibson

What is the meaning of wasps nest symbolism from Neuromancer ? When Case had some mental problems he recalled a memory of a broken wasps nest a few times.

Answer (score 13):

For me, it was a symbolic representation of Tessier-Ashpool. They are the result of natural forces, but seem very unnatural and alien. It is ruthless, efficient, and sleek: capable of causing great pain. But once thy have been brought down, they can seem almost pathetic and disgusting. Case would eventually bring both of them down as well.

Comment: interesting, let see if someone will come with different interpretation

Answer (score 6):

Tek's answer is great.

I'd also like to point out the "hive mind" aspect of the T-A clan, emphasizing the fact that the family's members aren't actually free-thinking individuals anymore - until Wintermute corrupts 3Jane's programming that is.

And the (perhaps tenuous) relationship between T-A's cloning cryogenic re-incarnation aspect, where the freezers are in a sense "staging areas" for further generations of cyborg-like killing machines ready to be unleashed into the world on behalf of the hive-family.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Neuromancer study guide out there that touches on this.  IIRC, the general idea is that the hive had a number of bees at different stages of development, all next to each other, in what amounted to a factory of little machine guns.

Besides the hive mind simile mentioned above, T-A is similar because of the way they clone (the cloning process being akin to larva developing) and cryofreeze their offspring (in cryofreeze chambers/crypts).  In their quest to create the perfect corporation stewards, including famed killer clone Hideo, within the hive-like cells that make up the corridors and rooms of Villa Straylight, the T-A clan has done some twisted things with people.